# How can I use JSON's `jsexpr?` predicate with Typed Racket?

Tags: racket, typed-racket

I'm trying to use the `json` package in Typed Racket, but I'm having some trouble handling how to type the `jsexpr?` predicate. My first attempt was simply using `#:opaque`.

```
(require/typed json
               [#:opaque JSExpr jsexpr?])
```

The trouble is that a `jsexpr` is *not* a struct, `jsexpr?` is simply a predicate that tests whether or not a given value fits a certain structure. In truth, a `JSExpr` type should look something like this.

```
(define-type JSExpr (U
                     'null Boolean String Integer Inexact-Real
                     (Listof JSExpr) (HashTable Symbol JSExpr)))
```

So then, I would just use that `JSExpr` type, but there's still a problem. Now I have a `(U JSExpr EOF)` type, and I need to convert it to a `JSExpr` type (I want to throw an exception if I get EOF). Therefore, I want to do something like this:

```
(cond
 [(jsexpr? json-data) json-data]
 [else (error "failed to parse JSON data")])
```

This *should* work with Racket's occurrence typing, but now I don't have `jsexpr?` defined! Fortunately, there exists [`define-predicate`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/special-forms.html#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fprims..rkt%29._define-predicate%29%29) to generate that function for me. Unfortunately, it doesn't work with the `JSExpr` type because a predicate needs a flat contract, and potentially-mutable data structures such as `HashTable` require chaperone contracts.

Alright, well what about typing the actual `jsexpr?` predicate to occurrence-type for `JSExpr`?

```
(require/typed json
               [jsexpr? (-> Any Boolean : JSExpr)])
```

Unfortunately, *this* doesn't work, either, because filters can't be used in `require/typed`.

I understand that the real problem is most likely stemming from the fact that `HashTable` is mutable, but that's not something I can change. I suppose I *could* write my own `(-> Any Boolean : JSExpr)` function, but that would sort of defeat the purpose of using the library.

Is there *any way at all* to make this work? A simple `ImmutableHashTable` type would likely suffice here, but that doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: ask @samth or vincent or asumu on the racket-lang mailing list or on IRC...

Comment: It seems to me that if `JSexpr` were a `struct` then there would essentially need to be a schema established beforehand, and that would sort of defeat the purpose of using JSON.

Answer (score 1):

From the mailing list:

> The problem is that typed racket doesn’t know that a value of type String for instance will be of type JSExpr or not, so you would have to put `(assert x jsexpr?)` around everything that you want to treat as a jsexpr.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it was created at some point after this question was asked, but there's a [`tjson` package](https://docs.racket-lang.org/tjson/index.html) for Typed Racket JSON manipulation. It uses a recursive `Json` type defined as

```lisp
(Rec (U String Boolean JsNull Number (Listof Json)
        (HashTable Symbol Json)))
```

that's mostly compatible with values that pass the `json` module's `jsexpr?`. The exceptions are in what it accepts as a valid JSON number, and that it looks like `null` is hard coded as the symbol `'JsNull` instead of being controlled by a parameter, but it's easy to parameterize `json` code to use the same one.

Comment: (I wish they'd gone with vectors instead of lists to represent JSON arrays in both modules...)